# What's the simplest way to create a Zend_Form tabular display with each row having a radio button?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I've seen simple examples of rendering a Zend_Form using decorators, but I'm not sure they are able to handle the issue I'm facing very well.

I query the database and get an array of user objects.  I want to display these users as a form, with a radio button next to each of them and a submit button at the bottom of the page.

Here's roughly what the form will look like:

```
   [user id]  [email]         [full name]
( ) 1         test@test.com   Test user 1
(*) 2         test2@test.com  Test user 2
[SUBMIT]
```

Is this something achievable in a reasonably straightforward way or do I need to use the ViewScript partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should easily achieve this layout [Leveraging Zend Form Decorators](http://static.zend.com/topics/Leveraging-Zend-Form-Decorators-2009-12-16.pdf).

**Edit:**

You may be interested also on Zendcasts:
[Zend Form decorators explained](http://www.zendcasts.com/zend_form-decorators-explained/2010/02/) and [Creating custom Zend Form Decorators](http://www.zendcasts.com/creating-custom-zend_form-decorators/2010/02/).

BTW, This is pretty common layout for preferences:

[Display preferences http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3244/displaypreferences.gif](http://planetozh.com/blog/2006/05/php-bitwise-operators-example-of-use/)

Once you are finished, post your working code here for reference.

Comment: Thanks!  I've seen lots of articles on decorators but that's the first that tackles things in a way that works in my situation -- templating with sprintf rather than just clothing an input in static HTML.

Comment: I have added two more links to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick suggestion. Why do you need table for this? The default definition list markup can be styled to look exactly like you want it to look.

Comment: I need 3+ columns per row and I need headers for each column.  Not sure how a list can ensure each column will line up with other rows' data and also with the headers.